# NSString sizeWithFont: for multiple lines?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, height

Is there an equivalent to NSString's `sizeWithFont:` method that can be used for calculating the height of text in a UITectView for a given width? All of the methods from NSString only operate on a single line from what I can tell.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From [Apple's reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893-CH3-SW5) for these NSString methods, you could use `-sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` or `-sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` for "Computing Metrics for Multiple Lines of Text".

```
CGSize size = [theString sizeWithFont:font
                    constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 100000)];
return size.height;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have used for determining the height of multiple lines.  Basically you just set possible height to some really large value, and get back the actual size that fits the text wrapped into multiple lines.

Comment: This seems to be returning a value 1-2 lines too small. Any idea why?

Comment: @Jumhyn: Try to the `-drawInRect:` method to draw the string out to check if it wraps at the right place.

Comment: Text drawn with `-drawInRect:` does not match the result of `sizeWithFont: `.

Comment: @Jumhyn did you ever find out why is the height to small? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

For `UITextView`, all you have to do is call `-sizeToFit` on the view, and it will automatically resize its height until it can fit all the text available. All you need to do is set the width of the text view, set the text, then call `-sizeToFit`. The text view will resize its height just enough to fit all the text.

**UPDATE:**

Apparently text views only shrink when there's excess height, but they don't grow if there's insufficient height to display all the text. In addition, once you call `-sizeToFit`, the text view's `y` coordinate is reset back to `0.0f`. So here's what you do:

```
CGFloat textViewWidth = 300.0f;
CGFloat textViewPadding = 10.0f;

UITextView * textView = [[[UITextView alloc] init] autorelease];
textView.text = ...;    // Really long string
textView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, textViewWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX);

[textView sizeToFit];   // Shrinks the height to fit all the text

textView.frame = CGRectMake(textViewPadding, textViewPadding, 
    textViewWidth, textView.frame.size.height);

[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

First, you set the frame just so you can set the width like you want it. You use `CGFLOAT_MAX` to pretty much indicate infinite height. Next, calling `-sizeToFit` shrinks the height until it just fits all the text. However, it also resets the `y` coordinate, so we go ahead and set the frame again to configure the `x` and `y` coordinates—in this example, `10.0f` for both `x` and `y`—, leaving the width alone and keeping the height set to whatever `-sizeToFit` calculated.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I clarified how `UITextView` is really working. Doing something like the sample code I added should result in a text view that is just high enough to fit all the text.

Comment: CGFLOAT_MAX caused some funky smearing/tearing on iPhone 5.1 when the UITextView resigned first responder and the UITableView scrolled back to the top. A smaller number like 1024.0f (long side of the iPad) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

actually, you could use the property contentSize.